# the password is not hashed when registering using AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created expanded the base user using AbstractBaseUser created my UserManager and added it to the new user model. when registering with createsuperuser, everything goes fine, but if I manually create a user, his password is not hashed.\

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

def _create_user(self, username=None, email=None, phone=None, \
                 password=None, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not username:
        if not email and not phone:
            raise ValueError('The given email/phone must be set')

    if email:
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        if not username:
            username = email

        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            **extra_fields
        )

    if phone:
        if not username:
            username = phone

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            **extra_fields
        )

    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser'):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            **extra_fields
        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(
        username=username,
        password=password,
        **extra_fields
    )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

# from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


from custumuser.managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username',
                                max_length=255,
                                unique=True
                                )
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',
                              null=True,
                              blank=True
                              )
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='phone number',
                             max_length=30,
                             null=True,
                             blank=True
                             )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined',
                                       auto_now_add=True
                                       )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='active',
                                    default=False
                                    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='staff',
                                   default=False
                                   )

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='verified',
                                      default=False
                                      )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        unique_together = ('username', 'phone')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I assume that objects = User Manager() does not work from the model. But I do not know why (

Comment: > but if I manually create a user, manually create means?

Comment: How do you create a User? Using `User.objects.create_user(...)` or `user = User(...) \n user.full_clean() \n user.save()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your customer user model in admin.py so it uses you `create_user` method.

[Then, to register this custom user model with Django’s admin, the mentioned code would be required in the app’s admin.py file:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)